# gson.fromJson(JsonReader,type) returns null

Tags: java, json, gson

This is my hole test code

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = null;
    try {
        jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/test.json")), "UTF-8"));

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stringList.add("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        stringList.add("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
        stringList.add("ccccccccccccccccccccccdd");
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setFucName("addXkg");
        data.setSqlList(stringList);

        gson.toJson(data, Data.class, jsonWriter);

        Gson gson1 = new Gson();
        File file = new File("D:/test.json");
        if (file.exists()) {
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

// jsonReader is not null and when comes to data2 it shows null in control panel

```
Data data2 = gson1.fromJson(jsonReader, new TypeToken<Data>() {
            }.getType());
            System.out.println(data2);
            for (String string : data2.getSqlList()) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
```

and it returns null in front of for() function,why?

Comment: 1. what does `in front of` mean? 2. have you tried to debug it yourself?

Comment: What have you tried? Smells like homework... See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `fromJson()` returns null if the reader is at EOF. Is the file empty?

Comment: my english is not that well, i mean the var data2 refers to null, and I try to debug it by myself with no help, the jsonReader is not null and I try to replace Data.class to new TypeToken<Data>(){}.getType() and it still not work, finally the file is not empty, sorry my english is bad..

Answer (score 0):

I find where went wrong, just delete the code above `Gson gson1 = new Gson();` and it works fine.
But someone who can explain this? Why...